# REDHAT: Unable to open eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, redhat

I am getting problem in loading the eclipse. It loads the workspace shows eclipse window. When I try to work, It got strucks with blank window.I am getting this error in command prompt.

```
An IOException occurred at scim_bridge_client_imcontext_set_cursor_location ()
The messenger is now down
```

Below .log file

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-05-09 07:23:18.586
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing     
workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2012-05-09 07:23:23.357
!MESSAGE Could not create view: 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview'.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.278
!MESSAGE Problems occurred restoring workbench.
!SUBENTRY 1 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.278
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 1 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.278
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 1 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 1 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE Unable to restore perspective: Workspace - Java.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE Problems occurred restoring perspective.
!SUBENTRY 3 org.eclipse.ui 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE 
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.279
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.280
!MESSAGE OK
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.280
!MESSAGE Could not find view: org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview
!SUBENTRY 1 unknown 0 0 2012-05-09 07:23:26.280
!MESSAGE OK
```

please help me out.. I am not getting what to do.

Comment: Can you profile the entire contents of the error log? (workspace/.metadata/.log)

Comment: @FrancisUpton -- I have updated with log.. please help me out thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the log it looks like some stuff is missing from your Eclipse installation. For example:

```
!MESSAGE Could not find view: org.eclipse.ui.internal.introview
```

is alarming. I suggest you reinstall your Eclipse.

The message you are getting (that you initially showed) it not likely related to Eclipse looks like it's related to the the use of vim:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=466876

If you have further problems after you have installed your new Eclipse, you can create a new workspace and import all of the projects from the existing workspace into it (be sure and select the "copy" option when importing). You will lose your workspace settings though.